Sign for SHM velocity squared function of x, given the initial conditions. Book error?
I am having an issue.

A particle is moving in simple harmonic motion with acceleration given by $\ddot{x}=-4x$. Initially the particle is at the centre of the motion and has a velocity of $12$ m s$^{-1}$.
Find the velocity as a function of $x$.

After I solve this differential equation, using $v\frac{dv}{dx} = a$
then I obtain a solution for $v$:
$v=±\sqrt {144-4x^2}$
Then because of the initial condition that $x=0$ (it's in SHM so the centre can be easily deduced as $0$ using the SHM definition of acceleration) and $v=12$, I deduce that the solution is the positive branch. But the answers says it's both branches plus or minus. Even when I graph it on desmos, the branch clearly are distinct and indicate that the positive branch should be taken for those given conditions:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator
Please help me.

You need to show all of your work here - edit the original post to do so. Hint: you didn't use the correct formula.

Just a quick question: what happens to the sign of the velocity projection in half a period when the particle returns to the centre of the motion? How does the positive branch handle that?

The particle oscillates between $x_1=-6$ m and $x_2=6$ m. When moving from $x_1$ to $x_2$, its velocity is positive; when moving from $x_2$ to $x_1$, its velocity is negative. Therefore, you need both branches of the square root.
